# Hyper-V nova-compute error

Tags: openstack-nova

I'm trying to connect nova-compute in Hyper-V with devstack on Ubuntu 12.04, but this error appears:

> CRITICAL nova [-] (OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column
>   'instances.server_name' in 'field list'") 'SELECT instances.created_at
>   AS instances_created_at, instances.updated_at AS instances_updated_at,
>   instances.deleted_at AS instances_deleted_at, instances.deleted AS
>   instances_deleted, instances.id AS instances_id, instances.user_id AS
>   instances_user_id, instances.project_id AS instances_project_id,
>   instances.image_ref AS instances_image_ref, instances.kernel_id AS
>   instances_kernel_id, instances.ramdisk_id AS instances_ramdisk_id,
>   instances.server_name AS instances_server_name, instances.launch_index
>   AS instances_launch_index, instances.key_name AS instances_key_name,
>   instances.key_data AS instances_key_data, instances.power_state AS
>   instances_power_state, instances.vm_state AS instances_vm_state,
>   instances.task_state AS instances_task_state, instances.memory_mb AS
>   instances_memory_mb, instances.vcpus AS instances_vcpus,
>   instances.root_gb AS instances_root_gb, instances.ephemeral_gb AS
>   instances_ephemeral_gb, instances.hostname AS instances_hostname,
>   instances.host AS instances_host, instances.instance_type_id AS
>   instances_instance_type_id, instances.user_data AS
>   instances_user_data, instances.reservation_id AS
>   instances_reservation_id, instances.scheduled_at AS
>   instances_scheduled_at, instances.launched_at AS
>   instances_launched_at, instances.terminated_at AS
>   instances_terminated_at, instances.availability_zone AS
>   instances_availability_zone, instances.display_name AS
>   instances_display_name, instances.display_description AS
>   instances_display_description, instances.launched_on AS
>   instances_launched_on, instances.locked AS instances_locked,
>   instances.os_type AS instances_os_type, instances.architecture AS
>   instances_architecture, instances.vm_mode AS instances_vm_mode,
>   instances.uuid AS instances_uuid, instances.root_device_name AS
>   instances_root_device_name, instances.default_ephemeral_device AS
>   instances_default_ephemeral_device, instances.default_swap_device AS
>   instances_default_swap_device, instances.config_drive AS
>   instances_config_drive, instances.access_ip_v4 AS
>   instances_access_ip_v4, instances.access_ip_v6 AS
>   instances_access_ip_v6, instances.auto_disk_config AS
>   instances_auto_disk_config, instances.progress AS instances_progress,
>   instances.shutdown_terminate AS instances_shutdown_terminate,
>   instances.disable_terminate AS instances_disable_terminate,
>   instance_types_1.created_at AS instance_types_1_created_at,
>   instance_types_1.updated_at AS instance_types_1_updated_at,
>   instance_types_1.deleted_at AS instance_types_1_deleted_at,
>   instance_types_1.deleted AS instance_types_1_deleted,
>   instance_types_1.id AS instance_types_1_id, instance_types_1.name AS
>   instance_types_1_name, instance_types_1.memory_mb AS
>   instance_types_1_memory_mb, instance_types_1.vcpus AS
>   instance_types_1_vcpus, instance_types_1.root_gb AS
>   instance_types_1_root_gb, instance_types_1.ephemeral_gb AS
>   instance_types_1_ephemeral_gb, instance_types_1.flavorid AS
>   instance_types_1_flavorid, instance_types_1.swap AS
>   instance_types_1_swap, instance_types_1.rxtx_factor AS
>   instance_types_1_rxtx_factor, instance_types_1.vcpu_weight AS
>   instance_types_1_vcpu_weight, instance_types_1.disabled AS
>   instance_types_1_disabled, instance_types_1.is_public AS
>   instance_types_1_is_public, instance_info_caches_1.created_at AS
>   instance_info_caches_1_created_at, instance_info_caches_1.updated_at
>   AS instance_info_caches_1_updated_at,
>   instance_info_caches_1.deleted_at AS
>   instance_info_caches_1_deleted_at, instance_info_caches_1.deleted AS
>   instance_info_caches_1_deleted, instance_info_caches_1.id AS
>   instance_info_caches_1_id, instance_info_caches_1.network_info AS
>   instance_info_caches_1_network_info,
>   instance_info_caches_1.instance_uuid AS
>   instance_info_caches_1_instance_uuid, security_groups_1.created_at AS
>   security_groups_1_created_at, security_groups_1.updated_at AS
>   security_groups_1_updated_at, security_groups_1.deleted_at AS
>   security_groups_1_deleted_at, security_groups_1.deleted AS
>   security_groups_1_deleted, security_groups_1.id AS
>   security_groups_1_id, security_groups_1.name AS
>   security_groups_1_name, security_groups_1.description AS
>   security_groups_1_description, security_groups_1.user_id AS
>   security_groups_1_user_id, security_groups_1.project_id AS
>   security_groups_1_project_id, instance_metadata_1.created_at AS
>   instance_metadata_1_created_at, instance_metadata_1.updated_at AS
>   instance_metadata_1_updated_at, instance_metadata_1.deleted_at AS
>   instance_metadata_1_deleted_at, instance_metadata_1.deleted AS
>   instance_metadata_1_deleted, instance_metadata_1.id AS
>   instance_metadata_1_id, instance_metadata_1.`key` AS
>   instance_metadata_1_key, instance_metadata_1.value AS
>   instance_metadata_1_value, instance_metadata_1.instance_uuid AS
>   instance_metadata_1_instance_uuid \nFROM instances LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   instance_types AS instance_types_1 ON instances.instance_type_id =
>   instance_types_1.id LEFT OUTER JOIN instance_info_caches AS
>   instance_info_caches_1 ON instance_info_caches_1.instance_uuid =
>   instances.uuid LEFT OUTER JOIN security_group_instance_association AS
>   security_group_instance_association_1 ON
>   security_group_instance_association_1.instance_uuid = instances.uuid
>   AND instances.deleted = %s LEFT OUTER JOIN security_groups AS
>   security_groups_1 ON security_groups_1.id =
>   security_group_instance_association_1.security_group_id AND
>   security_group_instance_association_1.deleted = %s AND
>   security_groups_1.deleted = %s LEFT OUTER JOIN instance_metadata AS
>   instance_metadata_1 ON instance_metadata_1.instance_uuid =
>   instances.uuid AND instance_metadata_1.deleted = %s \nWHERE
>   instances.deleted = %s AND instances.host = %s' (0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   'WIN-NVR4BLPKAS1')

Answer (score 2):

There's a column missing in instances table in the DB.

It may be out of date with the code; this command will update the DB:

```
nova-manage db sync
```

If the code is super super out of date, that command may not work super well, you may be able to either sync backwards, then forwards:

1. First find the earliest version with:

   ls nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions | sort -n | head
2. Then sync to that version:

   nova-manage db sync 112 # if 112 is the earliest in the list
3. Then sync forward to the end again:

   nova-manage db sync

If that doesn't work you may be able to go into mysql and add the column manually:

```
alter table instances add column server_name varchar;
```

Finally you could drop the DB, re-create it then do the sync (in mysql):

```
drop database nova;
create database nova;
grant all on nova.* to openstack@localhost identified by 'openstack';
```

That's assuming your nova db username+password is openstack and openstack. (You can get that from the [devstack localrc](http://devstack.org/localrc.html))

Comment: when i type ls nova/db/sqlalchemy/migrate_repo/versions | sort -n | head i receive that No such file or directory

Comment: and no command nova-admin, it works only with nova-manage db sync, but it doesn't return anything

Comment: nova-manage is correct; I've updated the answer -- when typing the 'ls nova/db/sqlal..' you should be in the nova source directory. -- if 'nova manage db sync' had no output, it may think that the the DB is up to date .. I would just add the required column manually in sql.

Comment: @matiu Thank you so much for the solution, with the following suggestions 
a. No need to specify the password in grant command.
b. Its the user "nova" in the grant command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue while I was expanding to more compute hosts, while I was troubleshooting the issue I found that I had different nova services version, I added proper repositories and remove the current Openstack compute and network service, re-installed and re-configure them again and everything went OK.

I was using Havana and below repositories were added. (I'm using Centos on all machines)

yum install http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-havana/rdo-release-havana-6.noarch.rpm

yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm